# Why is held expression evaluated?

Tags: evaluation, hold, upvalues

Context: I'm studying non-linear dynamics. As part of a bigger problem, I'd like to generate lists of the form `{{deq, ic1}, {deq, ic2}, ...}`, where `deq` is a differential equation and `ic` are initial conditions.

**EDIT**: (Use `r` instead of `t` for the tuples as per @Kuba's suggestion *)

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
deq = x''[t] == x[t] - x[t]^3 + x[t]^2 + Cos[t];
r = Tuples[{Hold@deq, {{x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, {x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1}}}]
NDSolve[First@r, {x, x'}, {t, 0, 1000}]
```

I have the following related questions:

1. <del>Why do I need to `Hold[]` `deq` at the first place ? If I don't use it, `Tuples[]` will "break" `deq` in == and combine all the `{lhs, rhs}` with all the `ic`'s.</del> It's due to the fact that `deq` isn't list which is what `Tuples[]` expects. See @Kuba's answer.
2. Why when later on I pass the result of to `NDSolve[]`, `Hold@deq` is evaluated without me releasing it first ? I checked the documentation of `Hold[]` and it says that this should happen only when the held expression is of the form `f[args]` and UpValues have been defined for f. I don't mind that it does, but I'm trying to understand the logic.
3. How would using `Unevaluated@deq` differ compared to `Hold@deq` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ad 0.** First of all, `t` in `deq` is not scoped so if you are assigning `Tuples` to `t`, the mess will occur.

**Ad 1.** You don't need `Hold`. From the documentation of `Tuples`:

> `Tuples[{list_1, list_2, ...}]` generates a list of all possible tuples whose i-th element is from list_i.

There is no list in deq so `Equal` is splitted. The proper syntax is:

```
Tuples[{{deq}, {{x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, {x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1}}}]
```

**Ad 2.** `Hold` is not released, it just isn't there.

Again, referring to the quote above, since there is no list `Tuples` is taking elements from the first head, which is `Hold`, so it takes `deq` outside and couple with elements from initial conditions list.

Take a look:

```
all = Tuples[{Hold[deq], {{x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, {x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1}}}];
NDSolve[First@all, x[t], {t, 0, 1000}]
```

> ```
> {{x[t]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,383.709}},<>][t]}}
> ```

```
all = Tuples[{{Hold@deq}, {{x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, {x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1}}}];
NDSolve[First@all, x[t], {t, 0, 1000}]
```

> ```
> NDSolve[{Hold[deq],{x[0]==0,(x^\[Prime])[0]==0}},x[t],{t,0,1000}]
> ```

**Ad 3.** i think this question may be skipped in context of the previous answers.

Comment: Thanks @Kuba! I will fix the code to not use 't' for `Tuples[]`. Also thanks for the hint on how to properly use the latter. Pretty lame PEBKAC. That answers 1. What about 2+3 ?

Comment: @Zet ok, see my edit.

Comment: Ok, _now_ I get it. The whole question is an epic pebkac, but I won't delete it just so that you get the bonus points you earned. Thanks!

Comment: @Zet Incidentally you wouldn't be able to delete the question anyway because of the existence of a positively-voted answer.  Also, while you may see this as a case of PEBKAC (I love that) it is nevertheless the kind of mistake that is easy to make with *Mathematica* and this Q&A may quite likely have value to others.  The power that makes *Mathematica* fun for experienced users also makes for some real head-scratchers!  Try to remember that because "everything is an expression" **many list functions will happily operate upon or destructure expressions with arbitrary heads.**

Comment: @Mr.Wizard & Zet well said, also, not only new users may find such behaviour inconsistent. In case of wrong syntax they may expect error or output=input. It's not the case here even though there is no info about working with any head in usage documentation. Only in Generalisations and Extensions section, but I feel it is not enough and so poorly made (in terms of logic and consistency) documentation (in general) is one of the big problems when working with MMA. The more that Wolfram is trying to sell it as user friendly software.

Comment: @Kuba I agree that documentation is incomplete.  I suspect that this is partly because full documentation would take considerable man-hours and also because it might appear *less* user friendly.  Instead one must rely on programming maxims, while fully accepting that they may be violated sometimes subtlety and profoundly.  The line I chose to **bold** above is one such maxim; always test a "list manipulation" function for yourself to see if it operates on other Heads; this is both faster and more certain that any documentation.  It also leads to many powerful uses and more concise code.